# Can I use this to power my 10w LED?

Tags: led

http://www.ebay.com/itm/181888372572?_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

I need to power a 10w(12v900ma) led using a 12v sla, can I power the LED using this 600w booster ?

(reason for using a 600w booster is I'm planning on buying a 100w led in the future.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. This is an adjustable voltage source - to power your LED you need an adjustable current source.

Additionally, this is a step-up converter, i.e. the output voltage is always higher than the input voltage. You can't use it if both sides are at the same voltage as you suggest.

You pointed out that there is a possibility to adjust the maximum current: A current limited voltage source is still different to a current source - it might or might not work, depending on the precise circuitry used. As an example: In the first instant, the voltage is at the set level, then the current limitation of the regulator kicks in - but there are some huge capacitors which might be connected directly to the output charged to the set voltage. The energy stored in those needs to go somewhere. The only place is our LED - they might get destroyed in this very first instant after connecting because of the much too high current.

Without knowledge of the circuit being used there are plenty more possible scenarios that can destroy the LED. There is just no way around using a proper current source for high-power LED.

Comment: But with that booster we can limit current. there is a pot to limit current.

Answer (score 1):

LEDs are current devices.  When you see an LED listed as 12v 900ma, the rating is 900ma.   That will happen at roughly 12v give or take.

If you take one of those and put 12v across it, it may flow 600ma, it may flow 1300ma.  Depends on temperature and age of the emitter.  LEDs are highly non-linear, they don't behave like resistors.

If you want LED lights which run stable on 12V-ish supply, they make constant-current driver circuits which turn that into exactly what the LED needs (for a wide variety of design currents).  You will generally need one driver per LED unless you want to wire several in series.

They also make preassembled LED products with emitter, driver, optics, cooling and case integrated, designed for a constant-voltage input of 12V give or take.